# How to switch connected sockets between node instances?

Tags: node.js, nginx, redis

I have spun 3 node instances using `pm2`. They are all running a `websocket` server using these ports: (9300, 9301, and 9302).

My main server acts as a `nginx` load balancer. The `nginx` upstream block:

```
upstream websocket { 
    least_conn;
     server 127.0.0.1:9300;  
     server 127.0.0.1:9301; 
     server 127.0.0.1:9302; 
}
```

After 10 players have connected, they are distributed in round-robin fashion. I am also utilizing `Redis` for `Pub/Sub` for all the `node` instances.

I am curious if it's possible for a connected player that is on instance `9300`, switch to `9302` while not losing their connection?

The reasoning is because my game is instance based. I have "games" if you will, that players can create or join. If I can get the **connected** players onto the same node instance for their games, I would reduce all the extra `Pub/Sub` signals and achieve better latency.  (Or so I think, but just curious if this is possible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am curious if it's possible for a connected player that is on
>   instance 9300, switch to 9302 while not losing their connection?

No, it is not possible.  A TCP socket is a connection between two specific endpoints and it cannot be moved from one endpoint to another after it is established.  There are very good security reasons why this is prohibited (so connections can't be hijaacked).

The usual way around this problem is for the server to tell the client to reconnect and give it instructions for how to connect to the particular server you want it connected to (e.g. connect to a specific port or specific hostname or some other means that your load balancer might use).

Comment: Got it. So I just need to tell the player joining what port to re-connect to, so they will both be on the same instance. Doesn't seem that bad, a trade-off of a reconnect vs not spending Pub/Sub signals for the entire life of a game --  Thanks @jfriend00